# How to show an image when loading iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am building an iphone app that needs to download many HTTP requests upon launch. Meaning that it takes a considerable time to load. The HTTP requests and responses are handled in viewDidLoad method of my viewController.

The screen is white when during this process. I am wondering whether there is an easy way to show an image instead of just white screen during this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MBProgressHUD http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in lots of places here in SO, you dont want to do this kind of work in viewDidLoad because thats your main UI thread. Do it in another thread and use the main thread to show an activity indicator or progress bar while you are loading stuff on the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is this (although I wouldn't recommend it, IIRC it "works") :

1. Display something at the start of your viewDidLoad (e.g. a UIProgressView)
2. Call [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate timeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]], which allows the screen to update (NB: I haven't typed those in Xcode, method names are off the top of my head)
3. Do your lengthy work

...but that will freeze the whole UI while it runs. The correct way is to run your image-loading in a background thread, and move it OUT of the "viewDidLoad" method entirely. e.g. use

```
performSelectorInBackground: ...
```

...which will let you pass in an @selector naming the "other" method you want to do all the loading work. This is designed to be very easy to luanch - you don't need to know anything about NSThread to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can display an image as the app launches and loads:

Click the project and a screen with orientations app icons and the Startup-Picture should appear; drag your loading screen into the to image containers which say "Launch images" one for the normal display the second one for retina display. Those two shall display while your app loads. Good luck!

Comment: Yep, although one danger here is that Apple may auto-kill your app when it's running on a real phone if it takes too long to startup. But you won't see this when testing, because when you run developer builds, the auto-kill behaviour is silently disabled.

Comment: Hmm... i never thought of that. Thanks for letting me now :D I'l up your coment cause' this stuff is important.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hud like [ATMHud](https://github.com/atomton/ATMHud):

```
// show hud
[hud setCaption:@"Working..."];
[hud setActivity:YES];
[hud show];

// ...do your HTTP requests here...

// update hud
[hud setCaption:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"done with %@",result]];
[hud setActivity:NO];
[hud setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"19-check"]];
[hud update];
[hud hideAfter:2.0];
```

The project linked has a simple example that you can run to see how it looks.